# how to retrieve the data from xml and display it in table in html

Tags: html, angularjs, xml

I wanted to develop a small search website where I will be storing the data in XML files. When we search anything, it should display those data as table format in html. How does one retrieve the data from XML files?

Below is the basic thing to display data of only two columns, but I want to display data dynamically:

html file:`http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp`

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11S7w.png) is the sample code for retrieving the data from xml only for two columns.

Comment: Please, **dont paste screenshots** of the text of your code, but provide your code formatted as code instead. It will help you. Thanks.

Comment: k this is the first time am asking the question in stackoverflow .can u know the answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first problem I see is that you have two functions in there that are not being called.  Nothing programmatic will happen in this scenario.  When you have a method you need to call said method with myFunction().  I would recommend reading up a little more on javascript instead of copying and pasting it and expecting it to just "work"

To further elaborate, you removed the function call from the example you took when you took off the button. What is your xml endpoint? (it's not going to be the same as the example unless you build it to be that way).  In this example it's just an xml file that is hosted on the server with the same root as the html.